# Running TestNG suite in parallel with Selenium Grid

Tags: java, multithreading, selenium, testng, selenium-grid

I want to run the same TestNG suite multiple times using Selenium Grid (for load testing).
For example I have a node with 3 different browsers. Selenium Grid allows to run multiple **different** test suites in many threads but I can't figure out how to run **the same** test suite in multiple threads in different browsers.

Probably some other approaches exist to run the whole test suite many times in parallel.

Comment: How are you triggering your tests?

Comment: I use TestNG annotations (without testng.xml) and maven-surefire-plugin with configuration:  
<parallel>classes</parallel>  
<threadCount>10</threadCount>

Comment: Just curious - why not have multiple jobs?  Send the browsername as parameter? - http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html

Comment: Yes, multiple jobs can solve this task. But as far as I understand, it requires more resources and some additional tools like Jenkins or JMeter. I am just looking for a convenient and easy to configure solution using Maven + TestNG if it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest versions of TestNG now gives you a new listener called [`IAlterSuiteListener`](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/master/src/main/java/org/testng/IAlterSuiteListener.java) using which you can now literally clone the `XmlSuite` object (the `XmlSuite` represents a suite tag in your XML). So maybe you can use that listener and through your listener duplicate a suite "n" times based on your need.

Comment: You really don't need a "@" when posting an answer to the question.

Comment: Krishnan, thanks for advice. I managed to duplicate tests at runtime like in your example here: https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/master/src/test/java/test/listeners/AlterSuiteListenerTest.java
I also tried to clone the whole XmlSuite object and add it to the list of suites. 
It works but I can't run the duplicated suite in a separate thread. Suppose we have a suite A and create a clone A1. When I run tests the suites are triggered consecutively despite configuration <parallel>classes</parallel> <threadCount>10</threadCount>.

Comment: Max:You can do it via the surefire plugin with the below entry
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <suiteXmlFiles>
            <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
        </suiteXmlFiles>
        <skipTests>false</skipTests>
        <properties>
            <property>
                <name>suitethreadpoolsize</name>
                <value>2</value>
            </property>
        </properties>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

Comment: Thank you, Krishnan! Cloning of XmlSuite objects in **IAlterSuiteListener** in combine with _<suitethreadpoolsize>_ parameter got the desired results.

Answer (score 1):

I use TestNG's **`@Factory`** with a **`@DataProvider`** to run my tests concurrently and multiple times per browser like this:

Base test class:

```
public abstract class AbstractIntegrationTest extends TestNG { 

    @DataProvider(name = "environment", parallel = true)
    public static Object[][] getEnvironments() { return PropertiesHelper.getBrowsers() ; }

    public AbstractIntegrationTest(final Environments environments) {

        this.environment = environments;
    }

    @BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true)
    public void init(Method method) {

        this.selenium = new Selenium();
        this.propertiesHelper = new PropertiesHelper();

        this.driver = selenium.getDriverFor(environment);

        login(driver);

        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "### STARTING TEST: " + method.getName() +"["+environment.toString()+"] ###");
    } 
}
```

Test class:

```
public class ITlogin extends AbstractIntegrationTest {

    @Factory(dataProvider = "environment")
    public ITlogin(Environments environments) {
        super(environments);
    }

    @Test
    public void whenLoginWithValidUser_HomePageShouldBeVisible() {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your implementation is thread safe and you are pointing to grid url in remote driver. You can configure it in your testNG configuration file. There are multiple ways to config it. Below is simplest example:

```
<suite name="Sample suite" verbose="0" parallel="methods" thread-count="3">
...
</suite>
```

You can refer [TestNG Documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parallel-running) for more details.

You can repeat xml test multiple times in xml suite file and run tests parallel. For example:

```
<suite name="Sample suite" verbose="0" parallel="tests">
    <test name="TestonFF">
        <parameter name="driver.name" value="firefoxDriver" />
    </test>
    <test name="TestOnChrome"> <!-- test name must be unique -->
        <parameter name="driver.name" value="chromeDriver" /> 
<!-- copied above --> 
    </test> 
</suite>
```

Comment: Yes, it allows to run tests in parallel. But the question is how to invoke test suite multiple times.
My test suite is built as a complex scenario with dependent tests. I would like to run the whole scenario (i.e. suite) multiple times in parallel. I know there is invocationCount parameter, but it works with methods only.

Comment: You can use a trick by repeating xml test multiple times in xml suite file and run tests parallel. For example:

<suite name="Sample suite" verbose="0" parallel="tests">
 <test name="Test onFF">
 <parameter name="driver.name" value="firefoxDriver" />

   </test>

 <test name="TestOnChrome">
 <parameter name="driver.name" value="chromeDriver" />

  <!-- copied above -->
 </test>
</suite>

Comment: It is possible but I would like to have dynamic configuration. Moreover I have many suites (configured with annotations) and it is inconvenient to duplicate each of them multiple times.